# If $L,K$ fields, and $L(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$ then $L=K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The question appeared in my mind when I was studying Field Extension(preparation for Galois Theory).

It is trivial that if $L=K$, and $\alpha$ algebraic over $L$ and $K$, then $L(\alpha)$=$K(\alpha)$

Is it always true that If $L,K$ fields, $L(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$, and $[K(\alpha):K]=[L(\alpha):L]$  then $L=K$?

I think it is true and I try to prove it via the following statements:

It is clear that the smallest field containing $L$ and $\alpha$ is equal to the the smallest field containing $K$ and $\alpha$. Then the smallest field $F$ containing $L,K,\alpha$ is equal to both $L(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$.

Thus $F\subset L(\alpha)$ implies $K\subset L(\alpha)$. Then we can conclude that $K\subset L$

Similarly, $L\subset K$

Finally, $L=K$

============================

Thank you all guys for providing trivial or non-trivial examples, the statement is clearly false.

Comment: $\mathbb R(i)=\mathbb C(i)$...

Comment: Well, a very nice counter-example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is False.

Consider the Field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ that, by Primitive Element Theorem, is generated by a single element $\alpha$ (You can choose $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, for example).

Now $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\alpha)$ is obviousely equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})(\alpha)$ and $$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$$ but the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are not isomorphic!

Comment: A good counterexample, because it shows the Question's hypotheses are not easily mended to give a true statement.